# How to rearrange daily stream discharge data into monthly format and rank the discharge values for each month using R

Tags: r

I have a data set of daily stream discharge values from a gauging station for approximately 50 years. The data is arranged into three columns, namely, "date", "month", "discharge".(Sample data shown here)

`

```
 Date<- as.Date(c('1938-10-01','1954-10-27', '1967-06-16','1943-01-01','1945-01-14','1945-03-14','1954-05-04','1960-04-23','1960-05-09','1962-01-18','1968-12-19','1972-01-15','1977-08-15','1981-04-11','1986-06-20','1989-01-20','1992-03-29'))

> Months<- c('Oct','Oct','Jun','Jan','Jan','Mar','May','Apr','May','Jan','Dec','Jan','Aug','Apr','Jun','Jan','Mar')
> Dis<-c('1000','1200','400','255','450','215','360','120','145','1204','752','635','1456','154','154','1204','450')
> Sampledata<-data.frame("Date"=Date,"Months"=Months,"Disch"=Dis)
> print(Sampledata)
         Date Months Disch
1  1938-10-01    Oct  1000
2  1954-10-27    Oct  1200
3  1967-06-16    Jun   400
4  1943-01-01    Jan   255
5  1945-01-14    Jan   450
6  1945-03-14    Mar   215
7  1954-05-04    May   360
8  1960-04-23    Apr   120
9  1960-05-09    May   145
10 1962-01-18    Jan  1204
11 1968-12-19    Dec   752
12 1972-01-15    Jan   635
13 1977-08-15    Aug  1456
14 1981-04-11    Apr   154
15 1986-06-20    Jun   154
16 1989-01-20    Jan  1204
17 1992-03-29    Mar   450
```

I want to calculate ranks for each month separately for all the years. For example: Calculate rank in ascending order for the month of January for 50 years. With the same rank value assigned to a duplicate discharge value. Desired output shown here:

```
>         Date Month Disch Rank
1 1943-01-01   Jan   255    1
2 1945-01-14   Jan   450    2
3 1962-01-18   Jan  1204    4
4 1972-01-15   Jan   635    3
5 1989-01-20   Jan  1204    4
>         Date Month Disch Rank
1 1945-03-14   Mar   215    1
2 1992-03-29   Mar   450    2
3 2001-03-19   Mar   450    2
```

Comment: Got it! Sorry about that. Updated the post with code for the input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any packages first convert columns 2 and 3 to numeric and then use `ave` and `rank` with the indicated `ties` method.  Finally order the result.

Note that the output shown in the question does not correspond to the input, e.g. there are three Mar rows in the output but only two such rows in the input so this will correspond to the input but will not be identical to the output shown.

```
Sampledata2 <- transform(Sampledata, 
  Disch = as.numeric(as.character(Disch)), 
  Months = as.numeric(format(Date, "%m")))

Rank <- function(x) rank(x, ties = "min")
Sampledata3 <- transform(Sampledata2, 
  Rank = ave(Disch, Months, FUN = Rank))

o <- with(Sampledata3, order(Months, Date))
Sampledata3[o, ]
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution is working! If I were to get the final output separately for each month then what should I do? I tried filtering Sampledata3 for the month of January and it did not print the respective rows.

Comment: `S <- split(Sampledata3, Sampledata3$Months)` gives a list of data frames, one per month.  The names of the list components are the month numbers.  If you just need it for only one month then for January, say,   `subset(Sampledata3, Months == 1)` or `S[["1"]]`.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I need! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to group by 'Month' and use one of the ranking functions (`dense_rank`, `row_number()`, `min_rank` - based on the needs) to rank the 'Discharge' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Month) %>%
    mutate(Rank = dense_rank(Discharge))
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this option. However the group_by function is not letting me rearrange the original data set into different columns for every month. Therefore I assume the dense_rank function is calculating ranks based on the whole data set. What I want is to have separate columns of date and discharge for every month and then calculate ranks for the discharge column for each month.

Comment: @Roger Not clear about your expected output.  Also, the image is not helping to test code.  If you can update your post with small example (using `dput`) and an expected output, it would be great

Comment: My bad! Sorry for not posting the code. I've updated my post now.